# Why am I getting this error in Visual Basic 2010? What does it mean?

Tags: vb.net

I don't know why it does this but here is the code linked to it not show in the picture.

In the `My.Settings` the type is `string`

```
    Dim cursorValue as BigInteger    
    Dim cursorPrice as BigInteger
    Dim xCursor as Decimal    
    My.Settings.cursorValue = cursorValue.ToString    
    My.Settings.cursorPrice = cursorPrice.ToString
    My.Settings.xCursor = xCursor
```

Error:
[image]

To Update Values Displayed:

```
cursorUpgrade.Text = "Cursors: " & cursorValue.ToString("N0") & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: " & cursorPrice.ToString("N0")
```

Comment: What happens if you try cursorValue = cursorValue + xCursor and cursorValue = cursorValue * xCursor?

Comment: VB evidently doesn't like to add a decimal directly to a `BigInteger`. Did you try converting `xCursor` to `BigInteger` first, then adding it to `cursorValue`? Perhaps as, `cursorValue += (BigInteger)xCursor`?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that a variable hasn't been initiated. What if you Dim cursorValue before the call?

Comment: xCursor by default is 1 and later on it will be 1.1. in the settings it's a decimal. That's the problem right? if so, how could it be fixed? @lurker

Comment: You have to decide what you want to get as a result when you add the `1.1` to `cursorValue`. Do you want to round `xCursor` first, for example? Or should you really be maintaining `cursorValue` as a decimal? That's up to you and what your needs are. But as it stands, you obviously can't mix the two.

Comment: @lurker it needs to be a decimal as only decimal can have the "." in a number. or can a string have it too? As you see in the image, if the xCursor = 1 then it will add 1 the cursorValue but if xCursor = 1.1 then it will multiply cursorValue by 1.1

Comment: well xCursor needs to be decimal to carry a "." in it and cursorValue needs to be a BigInteger so what are my options there?

Comment: If you know `xCursor = 1`, then do `cursorValue += 1` in that case instead of `+= xCursor`. For the case where `xCursor` is not 1, then you'll need to convert to decimal or other high precision floating point, multiply, then convert back to `BigInteger`. Or if `1.1` is the only other possible value of `xCursor`, then you can do integer divide and add. In other words, to multiply by `1.1` you would add `xCursor` to `xCursor` divided by 10 (integer division).

Comment: examples cause idk how to approach this like your saying. and could xCursor be a string and still be 1.1? could it work with biginteger?

Comment: Ask yourself, **why** does `cursorValue` need to be a BigInteger. Unless there's a very specific reason why you need to hold a (huge) number, I'd bet you could use Integer (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) instead. Then math operations would be simple.

Comment: already exceeded the integer limit lol.

Comment: @Eddie - What kind of maths are you doing that exceeds the `int` limit?

Comment: the objective of the game is to get to the highest number possible. its just for fun.

Comment: If you need to multiply an arbitrary decimal number with a `BigInteger`, and you know what precision you're willing to accept, you could do: `cursorValue *= (BigInteger)(xCursor * 10000)` then `cursorValue /= 10000` or something like that. That would assume a desired precision of 4 decimal digits after the decimal point in the operation. As I mentioned above, to add 1, just add 1.

Comment: @lurker put that in an answer and ill accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix `BigInteger` and decimal values in arithmetic directly in VB.

One way to handle this would be to scale your decimal value up by a power of 10 and make it a `BigInteger` and perform your aritmetic in the `BigInteger` domain. So, if you need to multiply your `BigInteger` by an arbitrary decimal number, and you know what precision you're willing to accept, you could do (assuming you want to maintain 4 decimal places of precision when multiply your decimal number):

```
cursorValue *= (BigInteger)(xCursor * 10000)
cursorValue /= 10000
```

In the case of adding `1`, just add `1` instead of attempting to add `xCursor`:

```
cursorValue += 1
```

Or, if you know you want to add `xCursor` as an integer:

```
cursorValue += (BigInteger)xCursor
```

Comment: i replaced cursorValue += 1 and cursorValue *= 1.1 and it gets rid of the errors but it does not update the numbers displayed. I use this to update the values displayed. It will be up in the question details.

Comment: i very confused on why it's not updating.

Comment: @Eddie the update I think has little to do with the numeric conversion and is about updating the display of values in VB. That sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? I got no clue.

Comment: @Eddie I'm not familiar with VB's display subsystem.

Comment: display subsystem? i just update the values displayed with `cursorUpgrade.Text = "Cursors: " & cursorValue.ToString("N0") & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: " & cursorPrice.ToString("N0")` but it's not working ever sense i changed to the code `cursorValue += 1` and `cursorValue *= 1.1`

Comment: @Eddie, sorry, by *display subsystem* I mean the mechanism by which VB updates the display when you change such variables. Without more context, I can't tell why your code isn't updating the display. What code did you have there before which worked?

Comment: the code that worked before is when cursorValue was not a BigInteger but was a Integer. It needs to be a BigInteger now.

Comment: @Eddie, as I said, this is now a different problem that you originally posted since it has nothing to do with getting rid of your compile error. But to take a debug step to narrow this new problem down, I would recommend changing this: `cursorUpgrade.Text = "Cursors: " & cursorValue.ToString("N0") & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: " & cursorPrice.ToString("N0")` to this: `cursorUpgrade.Text = "Cursors: " & "(value)" & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: " & "(price)"` and see if you get "(value)" and "(price)" displayed. That will tell you if the problem is due to BigInteger.

Comment: well i changed it to: `cursorUpgrade.Text = "Cursors: " & (cursorValue) & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: " & (cursorPrice)` and in yours you had extra `""` in the code that made it text not values plus not the full value names. it game me an error `Operator & is not defined for types 'string' and 'system.numerics.biginteger'`

Comment: @Eddie, that's not what I suggested. I had `"(cursor)"` as a string in place of the variable, `cursorValue`, so as to eliminate the data type as a cause in an effort to debug. Please try exactly what I wrote in my prior comment.

Comment: this error can be fixed by adding `.ToString` to the end of each value in the `()` but yet still does not update the values.

Comment: Yes. it replaces the value numbers of `cursorValue` with "(value)" and `cursorPrice` with "(price)" and updated them to display the text. I still don't get why i had to do that. Is it so we know if it is actually updating?

Comment: what is strange but works is adding `Dim addToCursor As Integer = 0` and instead of `cursorValue *= 1.1` do `addToCursor = cursorValue` then `addToCursor *= 1.1` then `cursorValue = addToCursor` It updates the values.

Comment: @Eddie maybe it boils down to what is `.ToString("N0")` doing to a `BigInteger` type.

Comment: `.ToString("N0")` if you don't know is for formating number like `1000` to `1,000`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having seems to to in the code in your linked picture

```
cursorValue += xCursor
```

Won't work if `cursorValue` is BigInteger and `xCursor` is Dewcimal for the reasons given in the error message. Instead you could use

```
cursorValue += New BigInteger(xCursor)
```

Comment: is this converting my decimal to a BigInteger or no? Can a BigInteger have a decimal number "1.1"?

Comment: The code creates a temporary BigInteger with a value equal to the Decimal which is rounded to an integer.